# Sporadic Groups for non-mathematician

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

I am fascinated by the [classification of finite simple groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups), and would like to understand a bit more about the involved elements. I have some idea what cyclic and alternating groups stand for, and I understand several of the (at least classical, not necessarily exceptional) Lie groups.

What I would really like to understand what sporadic groups are. As a non-mathematician, I am interested in practical properties such as:

- Do they correspond to specific symmetries?
- If yes, a symmetry of what kind of object?
- If yes, what is that symmetry? How can I imagine it?
- What is the dimension (and other property) of those objects which have that symmetry?
- Can these questions made concrete with the example of some of the smallest groups, such as the [Mathieu group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_group)?
- What group theoretical concepts are neccessary to understand sporadic groups?

I would apprechiate every literature suggestion (whether its a book or a review paper), or maybe some video-recorded lectures etc, with the restriction that it should be simple to understand (i.e. understandable for non-mathematicians).

That would be super-great, in particuar as I failed to understand it from conventional group-theoretical books/papers, and I wasn't able to find a lecture on that topic.

Comment: What about "Symmetry and the Monster" by Ronan?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thank you for that suggestion! I just finished reading the book. It was really nice, and it answered at least a few of my questions above (such as what the M24 is), and I know now what to search for, such as the Character Table.